# JOIN to obtain all the rows from the first table along with NULLs from the second table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables (`tblReps` and `tblDailyWorkingTime`). The `tblReps` table, i.e., the first one, returns 37 rows, but when I JOIN it with the second table I get 36 rows as the second table only has 36 rows that match the first table.

How do I go about getting the 37 rows back with a NULL result for the row that was not matched?

Here is the query that I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    tblReps.[sName] AS 'RepName',
    tblReps.sNote AS 'Type',
    RIGHT(CAST(tblDaily.sDateAndTimeStart  AS smalldatetime), 8) AS 'DayStarted'

FROM 
    [tblRepresentatives] AS tblReps

FULL OUTER JOIN 
    tblDailyWorkingTime AS tblDaily ON tblDaily.sRepresentativeCode = tblReps.sCode 

WHERE 
    tblDaily.sDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND tblReps.[sActive] = 'True'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the correct type of join to use in this case is a left join:

```
...
FROM 
    [tblRepresentatives] AS tblReps

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblDailyWorkingTime AS tblDaily ON tblDaily.sRepresentativeCode = tblReps.sCode 
...
```

In your specific case, you could still use `FULL` because this condition in `WHERE` would turn it into a left join anyway:

```
tblReps.[sActive] = 'True'
```

But it is better to express the intent accurately.

The same effect that turns your full join into a left join is actually responsible for the missing 37th row that you expected. More specifically, this other `WHERE` condition:

```
tblDaily.sDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

transforms your join further into an *inner join*. That is why the 37th row is missing from the output.

The reason for that happening is this. The `FROM` clause returns a null in `tblDaily.sDate` for the unmatched row. Because the `WHERE` clause logically executes *after* the `FROM`, the above-mentioned predicate excludes the unmatched row, since `NULL = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` does not evaluate to True.

What you need to do instead is move the `sDate` condition to the `ON` subclause:

```
...
FROM 
    [tblRepresentatives] AS tblReps

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblDailyWorkingTime AS tblDaily ON tblDaily.sRepresentativeCode = tblReps.sCode
                                   AND tblDaily.sDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

WHERE 
    tblReps.[sActive] = 'True'
```

That way the right-hand side of the join is filtered on `tblDaily.sDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` *before* the join takes place. Consequently, the query will return the expected 37 rows from `tblReps` complemented either with matching data from `tblDaily` or with nulls.

Comment: Thank you, Andriy that explanation was very helpful and makes sense to me. I have tested and I am now getting the expected result.